# Magento - Can I get the standard WYSIWYG editor to work for category descriptions?

Tags: magento

I would like to use the standard WYSIWYG editor for the category text in Magento. Or at least to have the option. Is there an easy way to 'enable' this, rather than use 3rd party plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of editing stuff in the database as Fiasco Labs suggests.
You can go into Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes.
Search for the field you're trying to edit (ie: Description.)
And then change the value of 'Enable WYSIWYG' from 'No' to 'Yes'.

This is the same thing but without doing it directly in the database.

Comment: In 1.4 I did not find it so straightforward, for whatever reason. Anyway, I got there thanks to the other answers then, but probably this was the answer I needed...

Answer (score 1):

Even after enabling the System Configuration setting, I had to enable WYSIWYG on the Category Description field on my 1.4.x.x installation. It was a simple database update.

You need to find the attribute ID for the Category Description.

Using phpMyAdmin, browse the eav_attribute table and find your entity_type_id 3 items. Look for attribute_code=description and entity_type_id=3. You should have an attribute_id like 34.

Now go browse the catalog_eav_attribute table and look for the attribute_id you found above. Scroll over to the is_wysiwyg_enabled column. This holds a boolean, 0=disabled, 1=enabled. Change it from 0 to 1, go flush cache and you should now be able to use the WYSIWYG editor in your category description field.

Answer (score 0):

For which text? For the category description you have the build in WYSIWYG editor. You can enable this at System -> Configuration -> Content Management -> WYSIWYG Options. By default it's enabled.

Regards

Comment: ...and so it is. On my 1.4 build it is not present as an option but on 1.6 it is. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do this would be to go to Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes. Select the attribute, and set Enable WYSIWYG to Yes.